# Are there are alts to Yumi multiboot creator tool for ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, yumi

i downloaded the .deb file for yumi from the pendrive website and went the software center opens the file, it says it cant install because the dependencies are not satisfiable : gambus3-runtime.
it tried to install it but its not it the default respositories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as other alternatives to Yumi, there is as stated by @Angel Salinas Huerta, Multisystem.  To install,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
wget http://liveusb.info/multisystem/install-depot-multisystem.sh.tar.bz2
tar -xvf install-depot-multisystem.sh.tar.bz2
sudo ./install-depot-multisystem.sh
```

As far as installing Yumi, you have to install gambas3 prior to installing yumi to satisfy dependencies.

To install, download [Yumi deb](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/YUMI/ubuntu/yumi_0.0.1-1_all.deb) file.  After the file is downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to where the file was downloaded (Probably the Downloads Folder), and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/gambas3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gambas3
sudo dpkg -i yumi_0.0.1-1_all.deb
```

That should install Yumi,  See images below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe you meant "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" instead of "sudo apt-get dist-update" (update/upgrade)?

Comment: @MladenB. You're right.  Got it fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

Multisystem, previously multiboot, works fine to me:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/

If you want to add repositories to keep it updated or download an iso:

http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/install